# Is there an option to flashing/restore Filesystem for Smartwatch 2 (SW2) using SUS

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

I have managed to as well as several other people to have damaged my SmartWatch 2 (SW2) file system.  The Unit boots but soon shows ‘FLASH FS’ issue on their devices.  I have read back on other forums dated back to Jan/Feb ’14 that a possible solution was to use SUS (Sony Update Service) to detect and reflash the watch.

However from my experience I understand that today the support for SW2 was removed from SUS currently so I think the above solution is not possible.  Does anyone know if there is a way (or backdoor way) to allow/force SUS to detect and reflash the watch without the need for Sony to redistribute the SW2 firmware (.dfu) publically?

Comment: How did you brick it?

Comment: I was playing around with SUS and actually flashed MN2 firmware on it.  I was planning to restore via dfu-utils and used the smartwatch.dfu on the developers.sony website and actually bricked it with this dfu firmware.

I restore the boot from a previous memory dump, but need to restore the file system, but can't write from address 0x00000000 using dfu-util via the -s option.

Sony don't have plans to share the dfu image for SW2, so last hope would be to restore via SUS if SW2 support can be enabled